# CodeEval Sum of the first 1000 prime numbers in java

Tags: java

Now I am trying to do an easy task from https://www.codeeval.com

Where you need to find the sum of first 1000 prime numbers. I done it in IDEA and my sum is same with correct answer. But when i try to upload my file to site it show error after loading:

```
"CodeEval Error: Compilation was aborted after 10 seconds".
```

I have no idea about this error. Any ideas about this error?

```
    public class solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           int sum = 2;
           int num = 3;
           for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
               while (!IsPrime(num)) {
                   num += 1;
               }
               sum = sum + num;
               num += 1;
           }
           System.out.println(sum);
        }
        static boolean IsPrime(int TestNum) {
            int NumOfDividers = 1;
            for (int x = 2; x <= TestNum; x++) {
                if (TestNum % x == 0) {
                    NumOfDividers = NumOfDividers + 1;
                }
            }
            return (NumOfDividers == 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: That means you need to optimize your code. Start with `IsPrime`: you don't need to check all numbers from 2 to `TestNum`.

Comment: I doubt there is much to optimize for compile-time. I had guessed it may have something to do with different runtime level but I see nothing requiring java > 1.6. No imports missing either. I'm frustrated at the non-standard class/variable/method case, but I doubt it has anything to do with it, unless codeeval expects a Solution class rather than solution.

Comment: Why do you count `NumOfDividers? You don't need that, just do `if (TestNum % x == 0) return false;` and at the end of the method, `return true`. Also, really don't check every number ...

Comment: yeah, only check to sqrt(testNum), since no higher than that is a divisor

Answer (score 1):

The simplest optimisation for your `isPrime` method is to skip most of the divisions like this:

```
static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    if (n != 2 && (n & 1) == 0) {
        // Early test for even.
        return false;
    }
    for (long i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is possible to improve on this using a list of known primes but that is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Starting from `3` and increasing counter by `2` is also a very easy optimization.

Comment: @Keppil - That is indeed better - requires an additional `even` test but no biggie there.

Answer (score 0):

CodeEval Java support has been acting up lately. I usually have to upload my solutions multiple times, because sometimes it will score them appropriately and sometimes fail on the error you mention. Try that, and then delete the ones it times out on. Not that you can't improve your solution, but I would say that that's not why you're getting that error.